# getting 401 even pass the correct access token

Tags: asp.net, openiddict

I am currently working on a .NET project with 3 APIs, one of it is an identity server implemented using OpenIddict. Below is the startup class for the identity server project.

```
public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    => Configuration = configuration;
    
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MailSettings1>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings1"));
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, Services.MailService>();
    
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
        {
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            o.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server.
                options.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("identitydb"),
                    opt =>
                    {
                        opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 10,
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorCodesToAdd: new List<string>() { });
    
                        opt.UseAdminDatabase("postgres");
                    });
    
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });
    
        // Register the Identity services.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 4;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    
    
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;
        });
    
        services.AddQuartz(options =>
        {
            options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
            options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
            options.UseInMemoryStore();
        });
    
        // Register the Quartz.NET service and configure it to block shutdown until jobs are complete.
        services.AddQuartzHostedService(options => options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
        services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddOpenIddict()
    
            // Register the OpenIddict core components.
            .AddCore(options =>
            {
                // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
                // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
                options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                           .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
                options.UseQuartz();
            })
    
            // Register the OpenIddict server components.
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                // Enable the authorization, device, logout, token, userinfo and verification endpoints.
                options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                           .SetDeviceEndpointUris("/connect/device")
                           .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                           .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                           .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo")
                           .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/connect/verify")
                .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect");
    
                // Note: this sample uses the code, device code, password and refresh token flows, but you
                // can enable the other flows if you need to support implicit or client credentials.
                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                           .AllowDeviceCodeFlow()
                           .AllowPasswordFlow()
                           .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    
                // Mark the "email", "profile", "roles" and "demo_api" scopes as supported scopes.
                options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles, "demo_api");
    
                // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                           .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
    
                // Force client applications to use Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE).
                options.RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();
    
                // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
                options.UseAspNetCore()
                           .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
                           .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement(); // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
    
            })
    
            // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
            .AddValidation(options =>
            {
                // Configure the audience accepted by this resource server.
                // The value MUST match the audience associated with the
                // "demo_api" scope, which is used by ResourceController.
                options.AddAudiences("resource_server");
    
                // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
                options.UseLocalServer();
    
                // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
                options.UseAspNetCore();
    
            });
    
        // services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddCustomDaprClient();
    
    
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    
        services.AddCors();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error");
    
        app.UseRouting();
    
        app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
    
        app.UseSession();
    
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.AddSupportedCultures("en-US", "fr-FR");
            options.AddSupportedUICultures("en-US", "fr-FR");
            options.SetDefaultCulture("en-US");
        });
    
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
    
        app.UseEndpoints(options => options.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default",
         pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Register}/{id?}"));
    }
    }
```

Now, I want to use this identity server to protect the endpoints of other APIs.

For example, let's say I have a "booking" API and I want to protect certain endpoints. When a request is sent from the UI, it includes a bearer token in the header (already implemented, using Next.js as the UI framework). I need to validate that access token and check if it is not expired.

booking api startup class

```
 public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    => Configuration = configuration;
    
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
            services.AddGraphQLSubscriptions();
            services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation();
    
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor()
           .AddCustomMediatR(typeof(Application.Anchor))
           .AddCustomValidators(typeof(Application.Anchor))
           .AddCorsAll("CorsPolicy");
   
            services.AddOpenIddict()
     .AddValidation(options =>
     {
         // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
         // to retrieve the issuer signing keys used to validate tokens.
         options.SetIssuer("http://localhost:5003");
         options.AddAudiences("resource_server");
         options.SetClientId("planner_ui");
         // Register the System.Net.Http integration.
         options.UseSystemNetHttp();
    
         // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
         options.UseAspNetCore();
     });
    
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddAuthorization();
    
    
            services.AddDbContext<TenantDbContext>(
                options => options.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("tenantdb"),
                    opt =>
                    {
                        opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 10,
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorCodesToAdd: new List<string>() { });
    
                        opt.UseAdminDatabase("postgres");
                    })
            )
                .AddCustomGraphQL(c =>
                {
                    c.RegisterQueryType<QueryType>();
                    c.RegisterMutationType<MutationType>();
                    c.RegisterObjectTypes(typeof(Anchor));
                    c.RegisterExtendedScalarTypes();
                }).AddCustomGrpc()
                .AddCustomDaprClient()
                 .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                  {
                      c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "myApi", Version = "v1" });
                  });
    
    
    
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    
            services.AddCustomDaprClient();
        }
    
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    
            if (environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "myApi"));
            }
    
            app.UseRouting().UseCloudEvents();
    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
    
            // app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                // endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles()
        .UseGraphQL("/graphql")
        .UsePlayground(new PlaygroundOptions { QueryPath = "/graphql", Path = "/playground" })
        .UseRouting()
        .UseCloudEvents()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapSubscribeHandler();
            endpoints.MapGet("/", context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/playground");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
        }
    }
```

but I always get 401 even if I send the correct access token using Postman. I send it as a bearer token. can someone help me to fix this

below you can see the booking api logs

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5005/api/Practice/uukuk - -
info: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler[7]
OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was not authenticated. Failure message: An error occurred while authenticating the current request.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
info: OpenIddict.Validation.OpenIddictValidationDispatcher[0]
The response was successfully returned as a challenge response: {
"error": "invalid_token",
"error_description": "The specified token is invalid.",
"error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2004"
}.
info: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore.OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreHandler[12]
AuthenticationScheme: OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5005/api/Practice/uukuk - - - 401 0 - 5.5527ms
```